# I'm looking for a word that describes that horrible feeling you get when you see something disgusting and painful happen?

Tags: single-word-requests

Extremely specific, I know. Hopefully, that makes it easier to answer.

It's just like the title says. You know when you're watching a program and something horrible happens in it along the lines of someone's arm getting bent back to an unnatural angle, and you shudder and cringe back from it.

Is there a single word to describe that feeling?

Comment: You mean a word for the revulsion you feel?  I guess nothing's really coming to me.

Comment: Hi MB, welcome to EL&U. You might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. *You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used*."  You can add this using the [edit] link. For further guidance, see [ask]. :-)

Answer (score 1):

gut-wrenching  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/gutwrenching) idiom

> Agonizing; extremely distressing, unpleasant, or emotionally
>   disturbing; having a severe effect on one's feelings.

As in:

> What a gut-wrenching loss for the young athlete, who poured her heart
>   and soul into this match.

and

> It was a gut-wrenching feeling not being able to help him. The Sun
>   (2007)

Saddening, shocking and upsetting are close synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

How about **[revolting](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/revolting)**?

Broadly meaning *disgusting*, *repulsive*; but, more specifically:

> to turn away in mental rebellion, utter disgust, or abhorrence

Examples of usage:

> Guinn is mercifully sparing with the gory details, though nothing can
>   make them anything less than revolting .

and

> In the midst of one of these revolting paroxysms Spike breathed his
>   last.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the word exists for the feeling per se, but such an event would be described as [**sickening**:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sickening)

> extremely unpleasant; causing you to experience unpleasant feelings.

The word can also mean "causing sickness", but it's arguably more common in the sense of "causing dreadful, horrible feelings."  It's a milder term in British English than in American English.

Examples:

> There was a sickening thud when the child fell from the tree and hit the ground.
>
> He managed just three games for his new club before his career was thrown into jeopardy by a sickening injury.
>
> The ground gave way under her foot, and with a sickening lurch of her heart, she plunged downward.
>
> The world witnessed the sickening consequences of modern warfare.